# Return a boolean value based on the booleans of two other columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to add a new column to a DataFrame based on the boolean values of two other columns. If one of the two columns has a true value, then I would like the new column to return, True. Only if both the columns have a false value, then I would like this new column to return False.

As I am pretty new to python, I have not gotten very far.

A DataFrame like this would be a good example:

```
data = DataFrame({ 'name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 
                   'has_a_pass': [False, False, False, True, False], 
                   'is_an_employee': [True, False, True, True, False] })
```

Anyone have any useful suggestions for solving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it was intentional that the `is_an_employee` field were strings and not booleans, but assuming theyre supposed to be booleans:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({ 'name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 'has_a_pass': [False, False, False, True, False], 'is_an_employee': [True, False, True, True, False] })
data['new column'] = data['is_an_employee'] | data['has_a_pass']
data
Out[49]: 
   has_a_pass  is_an_employee name  new column
0       False            True    A        True
1       False           False    B       False
2       False            True    C        True
3        True            True    D        True
4       False           False    E       False
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I cannot believe it was this simple, I was trying to go the function route for quite some time! Your help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
In [170]: data['new'] = data[['has_a_pass','is_an_employee']].any(1)

In [171]: data
Out[171]:
   has_a_pass  is_an_employee name    new
0       False            True    A   True
1       False           False    B  False
2       False            True    C   True
3        True            True    D   True
4       False           False    E  False
```